# CSS Media Queries For Mobile Devices Not Working

Tags: css, media-queries

I am working with media queries to start making my site more responsive. However, the media queries work perfectly fine on my PC (Chrome) but when viewing on a mobile device (iPad and iPhone) the media queries don't seem to take effect. I have the viewport tag in the head but am guessing I'm missing something else....

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width:320px) { 
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    #mainText {
        color: pink;
    }
}
@media (min-width:481px) { 
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    #mainText {
        color: blue;
    }
}
@media (min-width:641px) { 
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
    #mainText {
        color: red;
    }
}
@media (min-width:961px) { 
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1025px) { 
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: green;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: purple;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

<div id="mainText">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Try remote debugging the web page.  Everything looks ok it should work. Also as a side note phones use very heavy caching so try a private browsing tab to make sure your new styles are applied.

Comment: A screen of 1281px is still going to trigger @media (min-width:320px). You should try ranges instead.

Comment: I agree with ranges. Right now, I'm just trying to get it to work. I tried opening an 'incognito tab' within Chrome on both my iPad and iPhone and the queries still don't take effect... The text for #mainText is black when I see the page on my devices....

Comment: Is there something in your css with an important that might be overriding your rules?

Comment: Looks like you have a filter brightness added to the text. Because you're not using the webkit prefix chrome is simply ignoring it. Try removing the filter brightness 1% and see if that helps

Comment: Wow. Thanks. If you add as answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a filter in your css

```
filter: brightness(1%);
```

Now because you're not adding any vendor prefixes for webkit, chrome is just deciding to ignore it. You can either remove this rule or add the following to your css.

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(1%);
filter: brightness(1%);
```

Cheers and Happy coding!

Comment: What selector do I use for this? I seem to have the same problem. Also, how did you see that mwilson was having a filter?

Comment: @JimJimL You can use any selector as long as the class names match in the HTML. I just looked through the developer console on chrome to see that chrome was not applying the style. Cheers!

Comment: Now I'm confused, where did you get his app/webpage to go through the css in the developer tool? I can't see it linked anywhere. Also does that mean I need to apply brightness(1%) to all my objects!? Im sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: I could look through your code if you post a question. It's a little hard to try and figure stuff in the comments. I use FF and it shows me where the rules are coming from in the dev tools.  You dont have to apply it, it's only if you want the brightness of that element to be 1%.

Answer (score 0):

As your queries might overriding itself try something like that
specify min and max widths for your queries that are always 1px smaller / bigger than the previous one

```
 @media (max-width:320px) { 
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    #mainText {
        color: pink;
    }
}
@media (min-width:321px) and (max-width:481px) { 
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */ 
    #mainText {
        color: blue;
    }
}
@media (min-width:482px) and (max-width:641px) { 
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */ 
    #mainText {
        color: red;
    }
}
@media (min-width:642px) and (max-width:1024px) { 
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1025px) and (max-width:1280px){ 
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: green;
    }
}
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    #mainText {
        color: purple;
    }
}
```